# Can I safely delete the folder UWPNuGetPackages?

Tags: storage

I'm trying to delete unnecessary files on my computer and I found a reasonably large folder called UWPNuGetPackages under MicrosoftSDKs. Can I safely delete it? I tried searching for it but only got NuGetFallbackFolder, NuGet files, and NuGet cache.

Comment: I also have this question the folder is absurdly huge.